# How does JVM manage threads?

Tags: multithreading, jvm, kernel, multiprocessing

Recently I took a course on micro kernel, and I kind of build my own thread manager (technically it is a **process** manager, programs talk to each other via the system call interface that I implemented and no memory is shared) which now makes me wonder how **JAVA** does it?

**TL;DR**
Here are my questions(Assuming single core):

I have a **kernel** that manages all user programs, JVM also has something similar?

system calls like **create_task,send_2_task,receive_from_task** makes the program counter jump to my kernel, I can thus handle the communication between user programs. By the time I am done with the system call I have to reschedule which task to run next, since the state of my system is likely changed (ie previous task can be blocked if it is waiting for some messages by calling receive), JVM does the same when I use **wait()/notify()/run()/call()/get()**? I mean does these calls transfer the CPU slot back to the **thread manager**?

I have to turn on **timer interrupt** via an assembly instruction so that I know there is **at least one** reschedule in each time period (hardware interrupt handler jump to my kernel), but before that I have to save all the registers on the stack(**via assembly, something like push $1 to sp**), since by the time I leave the kernel, the scheduling algorithm will kick in....it will not just resume the previous task. But JVM only has access to system level APIs, thus no information about the hardware (ie the memory mapped timer address) or assembly instruction of the particular CPU, how did he manage the time slice and context switches??

I spend a good amount of time try to formulate the question, it is a little complicated with a lot of details, if its not clear, please let me know...

Comment: what makes you think the JVM is different from other programs running on a system?

Comment: hmm, interesting, are you implying that each operating system also provides mechanism to manage threads? I mean if I start off any program on my laptop I am pretty sure it has multiple threads running in its address space...JAVA's thread manager will make a **system call asking OS** to perform context switch and this special system call will make sure the address space is not changed (not switching to a new process)??

Comment: java simply provides common abstractions around platform-specific mechanisms.